# transform xml string by lambda java8

Tags: java, xml, lambda, java-8

I have `String` as XML. I'm trying to transform `String` by regexp:

```
public String replaceValueByTag(final String source, String tag, String value) {
     return replaceFirst(source, "(?<=<" + tag + ">).*?(?=</" + tag + ">)", value);
}
```

then create map with tag, new value:

```
Map<String, String> params = TAGS.stream().collect(toMap(tag -> tag, tag -> substringByTag(request, tag)));
```

and use map to replace values in XML:

```
public String getConfirm(String request) {
    String[] answer = {template}; 
    Map<String, String> params = TAGS.stream().collect(toMap(tag -> tag, tag -> substringByTag(request, tag)));   
    params.entrySet().forEach(entry -> answer[0] = replaceValueByTag(answer[0], entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    return answer[0];
}
```

How to write lambda expression without saving in array (lambda takes `String`, converts it by map and returns a `String`)?

Comment: Regular expressions are not the right tool to work on XML.

Comment: You need to be aware that your regular expression will match occurrences of the string within element and attribute names, attribute values, etc, and will produce invalid XML in such cases. A vast proportion of the SO traffic on XML forums is caused by people generating invalid XML as a result of careless coding like this.

Comment: Besides the incorrectness of this approach, the repeated “convert the entire string” steps are horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to apply all the elements of the `Stream` of map entries on your `template` String.

I'm not sure, though, how the `combiner` should look like (i.e. how to combine two partially transformed `String`s into a `String` that contains all transformations), but if a sequential `Stream` is sufficient, you don't need the combiner:

```
String result = 
    params.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .reduce(template,
                  (t,e) -> replaceValueByTag(t, e.getKey(), e.getValue()),
                  (s1,s2)->s1); // dummy combiner
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using an intermediate map you could directly apply the terminal operation, I'll use the `.reduce()` operation like @Eran suggested:

```
String result = TAGS.stream()
     .reduce(
         template, 
         (tmpl, tag) -> replaceValueByTag(tmpl, tag, substringByTag(request, tag),
         (left, right) -> left) // TODO: combine them
     );
```

This way you wont have as much overhead.